# Printing all primes < 1,000,000 to a text file

Tags: performance, c, primes

It takes a long time to execute and the CPU usage for the executable is about 25% while it is executing. Any ideas on how to make this faster?

**primes.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "primes.h"

/* COUNT will be how many numbers to
 * check and see if they are prime */
#define COUNT 1000000

int main(void)
{
  FILE *ftp;
  /* open the file for writing*/
  ftp = fopen("primes.txt", "w");

  printPrimes(ftp, COUNT);
  return 0;
}
```

**primes.h:**

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isPrime(int number)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 1; i <= number; i++)
  {
    /* if i is not 1 and i is not the number itself,
     * ...then, check to see if the number divided
     * by i has a remainder of 0 */

    /* If the number divided by i (i != 1 or itself
     * has a remainder of zero, return false
     * (the number is NOT prime */

    if (i != 1 && i != number && (number % i == 0))
    {
      return false;
    }

  }
    /* If number is NOT found to be NOT prime, return true */
      return true;
}

void printPrimes(FILE *ftp, int count)
{
  int number;
  /* is the prime number, the first prime, second, etc
   * that is the value the places variable holds */
  int place = 0;

  /* print all primes starting at true and going to count */
  for (number = 2; number <= count; number++)
  {
    /* if the number is prime */
    if (isPrime(number))
    {
    place++;
    /* print to number to the file*/
    fprintf(ftp, "%d. %d\n", place, number);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32727/discussion-on-question-by-user91656-printing-all-primes-1-000-000-to-a-text-fi).

Comment: How many cores do you have?

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1134851/109122 demonstrates a highly optimized, wheeled Sieve of Eratosthenes, that can emit 300,000 primes a second in VB.net on old hardware. Also, it actually fully factors every number (which is unnecessary for finding primes) so i have no doubt that it could be rewritten in C to run even faster for your purposes.  It is extensively commented, explaining most of the Sieve tricks in use.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are doing brute-force trial division, and not particularly smartly. For example, you only need to test odd candidate factors up to `sqrt(number)`.

When you want to find many prime numbers, a much better algorithm to use is the [sieve-of-eratosthenes](/questions/tagged/sieve-of-eratosthenes). It involves just addition, no division, and skips processing of numbers that are already known to be composite.

Comment: I didn't even think about Sieve of Eratosthenes. That's a good idea. Also, you're right, I do only need to test odd candidates.

Comment: Also I could change:                                                                                                for (i = 1; i <= number; i++)                                                                                    to                                                                                                                                 for (i = 1; i <= number; i = i + 2)

Comment: @user91656, which is what 200_success said by "...only need to test odd candidate factors..."

Comment: @user91656 That loop would fail for a power of 2 (1024), that loop would fail to see any divisor. If you wanted to use that loop, you would have to check for n%2==0 above your loop.

Comment: Lets' remember that '1' is NOT a prime number, so the loop, suggested by @user91656, needs to be tweaked slightly to start with 2 rather than 1 (and the code should be rejecting any user input that is < 2

Comment: It was surprising to me just how much it accelerates the test to limit the divisors to be not larger than the square root. Modern computer are so fast that computing small numbers is "immeasurably fast", so I checked numbers in the 2e9 range (which is of course close to the limit of 32 bit ints, which just goes to show). Of course dividing only up to the square root results in an acceleration by a factor which is about the sqare root, i.e. roughly 45,000, making it immeasurably fast again for small amounts of candidates!

Answer (score 21):

There are a few algorithms that might help you:

1. [The sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is the most simple to implement, but not the most efficient (still more efficient than your algorithm though)
2. [The sieve of Atkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) is a lot faster, but a bit harder to implement
3. [BPSW-primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie%E2%80%93PSW_primality_test). You can test a number for not being prime with this test, but you're never actually a 100% sure. It is just very very likely that if a number passes this test, the number is prime. According to Wikipedia no known counterexample has been found yet even though the first 2^64 numbers have been tested. It is however very likely that a counterexample exists.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about these algorithms. I will try to implement them.

Comment: @OP: Since the first 2^64 numbers have been tested, and you only need up to 2^20, you should be able to use the BPSW test with 100% confidence.

Comment: The Sieve of Atkins is *not* a lot faster than the the Sieve of Eratosthenes, not even theoretically. Theoretically, a "correctly" optimized SoA could be slightly faster than an optimized SoE (the difference is something like O(log log n), but i have never seen this demonstrated in practice, nor any implementation anywhere on the internet that could demonstrate it. Even correct pseudo code of an optimized implementation is exceedingly rare.  Also, BPSW is a single prime testing method, whereas the Sieves are prime range-finding methods, orders of magnitude faster at this kind of problem.

Answer (score 11):

you could start by removing the c functions from the header file.

Suggest placing those c functions into the primes.c file.

If that is done, then the primes.h file can be eliminated or reduce to prototypes for the functions ( except the `main()` )

placing code, in C, in a header file is asking for problems, especially as the number of files in the project grows.

Header files are for:

1) function prototypes that need to be seen across multiple files,

2) extern statements to make data visible across multiple files

3) define new types, for instance enum struct union definitions. The actual declarations of those types (the actual data) needs to be in a *.c file.

4) each header file should have statements to the pre-processor step of the compiler so the contents of the header file can only be #included once in any one *.c file. Typically :

```
#ifndef UNIQUE_NAME 
#define UNIQUE_NAME
```

and at end of the header file:

```
#endif
```

though `pragma once` at the beginning of the header file also works

Note: UNIQUE_NAME should be:

1) all caps with root words separated by underscores

2) is usually the same as the name of the header file with the `.` replaced with an underscore.  I.E. if the header file name is `Primes.h`  then the UNIQUE_NAME would typically be: `PRIMES_H`

When calling the function: `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.  Suggest:

```
FILE *ftp = NULL;
/* open the file for writing*/
if( NULL == (ftp = fopen("primes.txt", "w") ) )
{ // then, fopen failed
    perror( "fopen for primes.txt for writing failed");
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// implied else, fopen successful
```

I/O calls are very expensive, time wise. I suggest generating a table to contain the primes, then printing the table in as few I/O operations as possible.

Comment: Or as I like to call it, SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE

Comment: Specifically, the problem with defining functions in a `primes.h` is that if the header is included by both `alpha.c` and `beta.c`, then if you try to link `alpha.c` and `beta.c` together into an executable, then you will get an error about symbols being defined twice.

Comment: In modern C it may make sense to have (small-ish) functions in the header file and declare them inline in order to allow better optimizations. The inlining *per se* may not even yield the  most benefit, but having the code visible opens the door to better optimization for the compiler without having to do sophisticated LTO. (Besides, it has nothing to do with better performance; as I indicated, it may even harm performance to move the functions out of the header.) The I/O concern otoh is valid, but the typical printf call will not result in one ;-).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, those functions in the header file will 1) not be valid candidates for inlining 2) moving them out of the header is the correct way to handle the given scenario.

Comment: "will not be valid candidates for inlining" - [-finline-functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-finline-functions-940) and others seem to indicate that it may depend...

Comment: @HannoBinder,  You may notice that the functions are 'considered' for inlining and Optimization level must be -O3 and the functions must be declared `static`.    I can tell you, from experience, that functions that are more than 2-3 lines long are not considered for inlining.  Suggest just move the functions to inside the .c file and let it go at that.  Note: that inlining of the function does little beyond saving the `call` and `return` sequences.  One suggestion,. If your really wanting to get the fastest execution is put everything in Main() and use a much better algorithm

Comment: I agree that whenever (file) IO is involved, there is very little to no gain to be expected from inlining. What's a couple of thousands of CPU cycles compared to the time it takes to just write 0.5kb to a physical disk...